# Reference for a Maschke lemma for crossed products

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, crossed-products

Can someone provide a reference for the following Maschke lemma:

If $C$ is a semisimple algebra over a field of characteristic zero and $G$ is a finite group
acting on $C$ by automorphisms, then $C \rtimes G$ is semisimple.

Answer (score 7):

Theorem 7.5.6(iii) of the book *Noncommutative Noetherian Rings* by J.C.McConnell and J.C.Robson states the following:

Let $R$ be a ring, $G$ a finite group with $|G|$ a unit in $R$, and $S = R \ast G$, a crossed product of $R$ by $G$. Then the right global dimension of $R$ equals the right global dimension of $S$.

An algebra is semisimple if and only if it has right (or left) global dimension zero, and your skew group ring $C \rtimes G$ is a special case of the more general crossed product construction. So your Maschke lemma is a special case of the result cited above.

Comment: +1. It's good to remember sometimes that Maschke's Lemma and Theorem are really statements about global dimension. This is often the right point of view to generalize them to other categories

Answer (score 2):

This is also stated in the generality asked for as Theorem 1.3 (c) in [Reiten, Riedtmann: Skew group algebras in the representation theory of Artin algebras, Journal of Algebra 92, 1985].